# Query unique data matching all the subquery list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables called "membership" and "restricted".

Table: **membership**

```
+---------+--------+
| GroupID | UserID |
+---------+--------+
|   10001 |    605 |
|   10001 |    255 |
|   10002 |    605 |
|   10004 |    222 |
|   10003 |    605 |
|   10002 |    501 |
+---------+--------+
```

Table: **restriction**
  Table called **restriction** is having the restricted GroupID and the corresponding ContentID to which the group is restricted.

```
+---------+-----------+
| GroupID | ContentId |
+---------+-----------+
|   10001 |     33333 |
|   10001 |     22222 |
|   10002 |     22222 |
|   10004 |     44444 |
|   10003 |     22222 |
|   10002 |     44444 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to get the ContentID that is of all the group the user id belong to from the restricted table.

ie. 
As in the sample data for UserID = 605, the group ids are "10001, 10002, 10003", i need to get the ContentID which is restricted for all the group id listed for user 605.

The expected ContentID in this case is '22222'.

The ultimate aim is to get the list of ContentID's which is restricted in all the group for that UserID. If the ContentID is not restricted in any one of the group then the contentID is no more considered as restricted.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question... You are expecting ONE ID back, but the user is linked to 3 groups with ContentIDs... 22222 is the only duplicate though... if you are looking for duplicates, I can update my question

Comment: @ Schalk, Duplicate can be there, i need the ContentID which is restricted for all the group the user belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

The following gets a list of all the content that is restricted on *any* group:

```
SELECT m.UserID, r.GroupId, r.ContentID
FROM Membership m JOIN
     Restricted r
     ON m.GroupID = r.GroupID
WHERE m.UserID = 605;
```

To get content restricted on *all* groups, you can count the number of groups and be sure that each one is represented:

```
WITH ugr AS (
      SELECT m.UserID, r.GroupId, r.ContentID
      FROM Membership m JOIN
           Restricted r
           ON m.GroupID = r.GroupID
      WHERE m.UserID = 605
     )
SELECT UserId, ContentId
FROM ugr
GROUP BY UserId, ContentId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GroupId) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GroupId) FROM ugr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select contentid from Restriction rec join 
(
select COUNT(*) OVER () as totalGroups, groupid from Membership
where userid=605) as userMembership 
 on userMembership.groupid=rec.GroupId
group by ContentId,totalGroups
having count(*)=totalGroups
```